# ENOTFOUND Error while installing cordova via npm

Tags: installation, npm

I get an `errno ENOTFOUND` error when trying to install cordova via `npm`.

This is the command I'm using:

```
sena$ sudo npm install -g cordova npm
```

And this is the response:

> ERR! Darwin 14.3.0 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
>   npm ERR! node v4.1.0 npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3 npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm
>   ERR! errno ENOTFOUND npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
>
> npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org
>   registry.npmjs.org:443 npm ERR! network This is most likely not a
>   problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and is related to network
>   connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or
>   have bad network settings. npm ERR! network  npm ERR! network If you
>   are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy'
>   config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: Add some more details and tags about the question.

Comment: That looks like an issue with your internet connection. Are you behind a proxy or firewall that could be messing with `npm`'s requests to the registry?